# jquery autocomplete focused item increases font size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

working on jquery autocomplete
trying to enlarge font size of focused item to distinguish itself using:
css: `li.focused { font-size:16px; }`

in jquery autocomplete delegate focus event to handler:
`focus: autocompleteItemFocusedHandler,`

In `function autocompleteItemFocusedHandler(event, ui) {}`
can get the focused item by ui.item
first attempt is to change the label:
`ui.item.label = '<a class="focused">' + ui.item.value + "</a>";`
however, it's not ok

also, i wanted to use jquery addClass() but never manage to do so

full playground:
https://jsfiddle.net/o7g2cb7z/17/
mainly css line 24, javascript line 84-86, 106

glad to see any advice

Comment: you want to increase font-size of input button ???

Comment: And only for explain: `li.focused` cant work in your case. You set secific on `li` like `<li class="focused">focus content</li>` not `<li><a class="focused">focus content</a></li>`. You have to set css selector to `li a.focused { font-size: 16px }`! But please check the answer from user `Arg0n`. thats the right way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the class set by jQuery:

```
.ui-state-focus {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

(Instead of `li.focused`)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/o7g2cb7z/18/)

Comment: you made it so simple~ is there a way to manipulate the focused element? my attempt is to get focused item and add the focused class

Comment: Well, try selecting it with jQuery and then manipulating it: `$('.ui-state-focus')...`. Maybe post another question if this question is answered.